# Store custom Groovy function in JMeter UI

Tags: groovy, jmeter, beanshell

Been struggling with this a lot lately: How do I store a custom Groovy script with imports etc in the JMeter UI so I can reuse it later?

- I don't want to alter JMeter startup property files in any way
- I want to be able to call this Groovy 20+ times within the JMX with different parameters

From the JMeter doc:

> Once the script is working properly, it can be stored as a variable on
> the Test Plan. The script variable can then be used to create the
> function call.

The groovy (compatible with Beanshell) is 62 lines and includes imports of custom JAR files. If I could store this as a var callable with `__groovy(param)` that would be great, I don't see how to do that from the docs. Setting up 20 `JSR223`s is incredibly clunky but I am coming up with workarounds if there is no JMeter way to do this.

References:
https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#developing_scripts

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you're trying to achieve:

1. There is a possibility to specify a path to the file with your code in any of [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) so you won't have to copy and paste it multiple times into "Script" area so in case of changes you will need to amend it in one place only:

   [image]
2. There is [`groovy.utilities` property](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#groovy) where you can specify the path to your .groovy file containing the logic callable from the __groovy() function, it defaults to `bin/utility.groovy`
3. You can compile your code to .jar file and store it under [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath), this way you will be able to call your functions from any place. See [How to Reuse Your JMeter Code with JAR Files and Save Time](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-reuse-your-jmeter-code-with-jar-files-and-save-time) article for example implementation/usage details

Comment: Interesting, useful links. The use case is: I have HTTP Request Samplers that require Groovy/Beanshell to encrypt 20 different variables during each test execution. For now, I am using JSR223 PreProcessor with the 20 params and putting encrypted output in vars.put(XXX..). It would be cooler and more elegant to have ${__groovy(customEncrypt(fieldAof20)} within the body of the HTTP Request Sampler. The custom groovy script has imports and is complex. Is this not possible? Any idea?